# SQLite Db is not responding (not readable) after a consecutive set of db calls

Tags: jquery, angularjs, sqlite

I'm developing an app using angularjs, jQuery & SQLite, where in i do operations on SQLite db.

I'm doing db calls in app where in db is responding properly but after usage of app for sometime, db operations are not responded even reading db..

Also i have a problem on memory leakage will it effect db and its operations ??

It would be thankful if there is any solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

You have an open transaction somewhere. If you turn on Write Ahead Logging, WAL, you will see your WAL file created and the size increase.

There's also a way to see open transactions/cursors, not sure what the command is though, or if thats valid for SQLite

edit:

IMO its good practice to close the database connection after every transaction and not have long running logic while its open

Also, the memory leakage would definitely affect performance! It could be a side effect of your first problem though, so I would solve that problem first and then see if you still have the memory leakage.

Comment: i checked my cache folder of app it is having Cache.db-wal file it is of size 4Mb i didnot get the term WAL what excatly it does please could you give a breif description

Comment: Write Ahead Logging, it means if the database is in the middle of a data altering transaction, any write to the database will be cached in a db-wal file and will be executed after the database is free'd. You should look it up for specifics, theres special rules and other stuff I'm sure I'm missing, but you get the idea. edit -- the fact that you have the WAL file and its a large size backs up my hypothesis. Do you have logs when you open and close the connection to the database, I would start there and make sure every time you open a connection you close it as well.